# Horizontal stacked bar: one tick not displaying

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart, stacked-chart, stacked-area-chart

Please can somebody tell me why the bar in top right corner is more elevated than all the others? When I use larger data-set it actually creates a stacked bar with multiple parts that seems not to be part of the chart and there is no right y axis tick value for it.

```js
var dataset = [
    {
        "stopId": "165",
        "data": [
            {
                "yValue": "101000017",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "10:53:00",
                "stopId": "165",
                "passengers": 12
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000018",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "11:23:00",
                "stopId": "165",
                "passengers": 22
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000019",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "11:53:00",
                "stopId": "165",
                "passengers": 6
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000020",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "12:23:00",
                "stopId": "165",
                "passengers": 14
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000021",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "12:51:00",
                "stopId": "165",
                "passengers": 13
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000022",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "13:24:00",
                "stopId": "165",
                "passengers": 21
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000023",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "13:54:00",
                "stopId": "165",
                "passengers": 28
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000024",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "14:24:00",
                "stopId": "165",
                "passengers": 28
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000025",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "14:54:00",
                "stopId": "165",
                "passengers": 4
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000026",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "15:23:00",
                "stopId": "165",
                "passengers": 18
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000027",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "15:55:00",
                "stopId": "165",
                "passengers": 5
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000028",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:10:00",
                "stopId": "165",
                "passengers": 27
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000029",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:25:00",
                "stopId": "165",
                "passengers": 6
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000030",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:38:00",
                "stopId": "165",
                "passengers": 18
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000031",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:55:00",
                "stopId": "165",
                "passengers": 26
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000032",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "17:10:00",
                "stopId": "165",
                "passengers": 29
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000033",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "17:25:00",
                "stopId": "165",
                "passengers": 24
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000034",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "17:40:00",
                "stopId": "165",
                "passengers": 29
            }
        ],
        "name": "Passengers"
    },
    {
        "stopId": "65",
        "data": [       
            {
                "yValue": "101000017",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "10:54:00",
                "stopId": "65",
                "passengers": 20
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000018",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "11:24:00",
                "stopId": "65",
                "passengers": 22
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000019",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "11:54:00",
                "stopId": "65",
                "passengers": 8
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000020",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "12:24:00",
                "stopId": "65",
                "passengers": 27
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000021",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "12:52:00",
                "stopId": "65",
                "passengers": 26
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000022",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "13:25:00",
                "stopId": "65",
                "passengers": 24
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000023",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "13:55:00",
                "stopId": "65",
                "passengers": 25
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000024",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "14:25:00",
                "stopId": "65",
                "passengers": 28
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000025",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "14:55:00",
                "stopId": "65",
                "passengers": 7
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000026",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "15:24:00",
                "stopId": "65",
                "passengers": 23
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000027",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "15:56:00",
                "stopId": "65",
                "passengers": 18
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000028",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:11:00",
                "stopId": "65",
                "passengers": 4
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000029",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:26:00",
                "stopId": "65",
                "passengers": 29
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000030",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:39:00",
                "stopId": "65",
                "passengers": 19
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000031",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:56:00",
                "stopId": "65",
                "passengers": 28
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000032",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "17:11:00",
                "stopId": "65",
                "passengers": 21
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000033",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "17:26:00",
                "stopId": "65",
                "passengers": 26
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000034",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "17:41:00",
                "stopId": "65",
                "passengers": 19
            }
        ],
        "name": "Passengers"
    },
    {
        "stopId": "63",
        "data": [
            {
                "yValue": "101000017",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "10:55:00",
                "stopId": "63",
                "passengers": 10
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000018",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "11:25:00",
                "stopId": "63",
                "passengers": 9
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000019",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "11:55:00",
                "stopId": "63",
                "passengers": 21
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000020",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "12:25:00",
                "stopId": "63",
                "passengers": 28
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000021",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "12:53:00",
                "stopId": "63",
                "passengers": 8
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000022",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "13:26:00",
                "stopId": "63",
                "passengers": 13
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000023",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "13:56:00",
                "stopId": "63",
                "passengers": 29
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000024",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "14:26:00",
                "stopId": "63",
                "passengers": 28
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000025",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "14:56:00",
                "stopId": "63",
                "passengers": 14
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000026",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "15:25:00",
                "stopId": "63",
                "passengers": 30
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000027",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "15:57:00",
                "stopId": "63",
                "passengers": 21
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000028",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:12:00",
                "stopId": "63",
                "passengers": 10
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000029",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:27:00",
                "stopId": "63",
                "passengers": 16
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000030",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:40:00",
                "stopId": "63",
                "passengers": 24
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000031",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:57:00",
                "stopId": "63",
                "passengers": 3
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000032",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "17:12:00",
                "stopId": "63",
                "passengers": 15
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000033",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "17:27:00",
                "stopId": "63",
                "passengers": 23
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000034",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "17:42:00",
                "stopId": "63",
                "passengers": 21
            }
        ],
        "name": "Passengers"
    },
    {
        "stopId": "47",
        "data": [
            {
                "yValue": "101000017",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "10:56:00",
                "stopId": "47",
                "passengers": 13
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000018",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "11:26:00",
                "stopId": "47",
                "passengers": 7
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000019",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "11:56:00",
                "stopId": "47",
                "passengers": 21
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000020",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "12:26:00",
                "stopId": "47",
                "passengers": 22
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000021",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "12:54:00",
                "stopId": "47",
                "passengers": 28
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000022",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "13:27:00",
                "stopId": "47",
                "passengers": 30
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000023",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "13:57:00",
                "stopId": "47",
                "passengers": 20
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000024",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "14:27:00",
                "stopId": "47",
                "passengers": 17
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000025",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "14:57:00",
                "stopId": "47",
                "passengers": 14
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000026",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "15:26:00",
                "stopId": "47",
                "passengers": 11
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000027",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "15:58:00",
                "stopId": "47",
                "passengers": 28
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000028",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:13:00",
                "stopId": "47",
                "passengers": 7
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000029",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:28:00",
                "stopId": "47",
                "passengers": 24
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000030",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:41:00",
                "stopId": "47",
                "passengers": 29
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000031",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:58:00",
                "stopId": "47",
                "passengers": 19
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000032",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "17:13:00",
                "stopId": "47",
                "passengers": 23
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000033",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "17:28:00",
                "stopId": "47",
                "passengers": 19
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000034",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "17:43:00",
                "stopId": "47",
                "passengers": 12
            }
        ],
        "name": "Passengers"
    },
    {
        "stopId": "185",
        "data": [
            {
                "yValue": "101000026",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "15:27:00",
                "stopId": "185",
                "passengers": 23
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000027",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "15:59:00",
                "stopId": "185",
                "passengers": 11
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000028",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:14:00",
                "stopId": "185",
                "passengers": 24
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000029",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:29:00",
                "stopId": "185",
                "passengers": 16
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000030",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:42:00",
                "stopId": "185",
                "passengers": 22
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000031",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:59:00",
                "stopId": "185",
                "passengers": 23
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000032",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "17:14:00",
                "stopId": "185",
                "passengers": 27
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000033",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "17:29:00",
                "stopId": "185",
                "passengers": 29
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000034",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "17:44:00",
                "stopId": "185",
                "passengers": 24
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000035",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "17:59:00",
                "stopId": "185",
                "passengers": 19
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000036",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "18:14:00",
                "stopId": "185",
                "passengers": 23
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000037",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "18:29:00",
                "stopId": "185",
                "passengers": 6
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000038",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "18:44:00",
                "stopId": "185",
                "passengers": 24
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000039",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "18:59:00",
                "stopId": "185",
                "passengers": 26
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000040",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "19:29:00",
                "stopId": "185",
                "passengers": 21
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000041",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "19:59:00",
                "stopId": "185",
                "passengers": 23
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000042",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "20:25:00",
                "stopId": "185",
                "passengers": 20
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000043",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "21:25:00",
                "stopId": "185",
                "passengers": 29
            }
        ],
        "name": "Passengers"
    }
];

var margins = {
  top: 12,
  left: 100,
  right: 50,
  bottom: 34
};

var numberOfRecords = 0;
var dataset = dataset.map(function(d) {
  numberOfRecords = 0;
  return d.data.map(function(o, i) {
    numberOfRecords++;
    return {
      y: o.xValue,
      x: o.yValue,
      name: d.name,
      stopId: o.stopId,
      passengers: o.passengers,
      time: o.time
    };
  });
});
d3.select(window).on("resize", throttle);
var stack = d3.layout.stack();
stack(dataset);
var dataset = dataset.map(function(group) {
  return group.map(function(d) {
    // Invert the x and y values, and y0 becomes x0
    return {
      x: d.y,
      y: d.x,
      x0: d.y0,
      name: d.name,
      stopId: d.stopId,
      passengers: d.passengers,
      time: d.time
    };
  });
});
var yValuesTripId = dataset[0].map(function(d) {
  return d.y;
});
var yValuesFirstStopTimes = dataset[0].map(function(d) {
  // return (d.time.slice(0, -3) + (Math.floor(Math.random() * (20000 - 1 + 1)) + 1));
  return removeSecondsFromHHMMSS(d.time);
});
var yValuesLastStopTimes = dataset[dataset.length - 1].map(function(d) {
  // return (d.time.slice(0, -3) + (Math.floor(Math.random() * (20000 - 1 + 1)) + 1));
  return removeSecondsFromHHMMSS(d.time);
});
var xMax = d3.max(dataset, function(group) {
  return d3.max(group, function(d) {
    return d.x + d.x0;
  });
});
var tooltip = d3.select("#chartDiv")
  .append('div')
  .attr('id', 'tooltip')
  .attr('class', 'hidden');

const chartArea = $("#chartDiv");
var width = chartArea.innerWidth() - margins.left - margins.right;
var barHeight = 10;
var height = (numberOfRecords * 15) - margins.top - margins.bottom;
var svg, xScale, yScaleLeft, yScaleRight, rects;

draw(width, height);

function draw(width, height) {

  svg = d3.select("#chartDiv")
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', width + margins.left + margins.right)
    .attr('height', height + margins.top + margins.bottom)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margins.left + ',' + margins.top + ')');
    
  xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, xMax])
    .range([0, width - margins.right]);

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient('bottom')
    .ticks(0);

    yScaleLeft = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(yValuesTripId)
        .rangeRoundBands([0, height], .1); 
    var yAxisLeft = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yScaleLeft)
        .orient('left')
        .tickFormat(function(d, i) {
            return yValuesFirstStopTimes[i];
        });

    yScaleRight = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(yValuesTripId)
        .rangeRoundBands([0, height], .1);
    var yAxisRight = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yScaleRight)
        .orient('right')
        .tickPadding(-25)
        .tickFormat(function(d, i) {
            return yValuesLastStopTimes[i];
        });

  var groups = svg.selectAll('g')
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append('g');

  rects = groups.selectAll('rect')
    .data(function(d) {
      return d;
    })
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x', function(d) {
      return xScale(d.x0);
    })
    .attr('y', function(d, i) {
      return yScaleLeft(d.y);
    })
    .attr('height', function(d) {
      return barHeight;
    })
    .attr('width', function(d) {
      return xScale(d.x);
    })
    .attr('fill', function(d) {
      return getColor(d.passengers);
    })
    .attr('stroke', 'white')
    .on('mouseover', function(d) {

      var xPos = d3.event.pageX - 310;
      var yPos = d3.event.pageY - 110;

      d3.select('#tooltip')
        .style("left", xPos + "px")
        .style("top", yPos + "px")
        .style('width', '250px')
        .text("Trip " + d.y + '|Passengers:' + d.passengers + '|Stop ' + d.stopId + '|time ' + removeSecondsFromHHMMSS(d.time));

      d3.select('#tooltip').classed('hidden', false);
    })
    .on('mouseout', function() {
      d3.select('#tooltip').classed('hidden', true);
    });
  svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis')
    .attr('id','busOccupancyChartXAxis')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
    .call(xAxis);
  svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis')
    .call(yAxisLeft);
  svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", 0 - margins.left)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .text("Departure Time");
  const newWidth = width - 20;
  svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis')
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + newWidth + ",0)")
    .call(yAxisRight);
svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", width - margins.right + 10)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .text("Arrival Time");
}

function redraw() {
  width = chartArea.innerWidth() - margins.left - margins.right;
  d3.select('svg').remove();
  d3.select('#legend').remove();
  draw(width, height);
}
var throttleTimer;

function throttle() {
  window.clearTimeout(throttleTimer);
  throttleTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
    redraw();
  }, 200);
}

function getColor(numberOfPassengers) {
  cellColor = "";
  if (numberOfPassengers < 10) {
    cellColor = "#585858";
  } else if (numberOfPassengers < 20) {
    cellColor = "#FFCC00";
  } else if (numberOfPassengers < 25) {
    cellColor = "#FF3300";
  } else {
    cellColor = "#A00000";
  }
  return cellColor;
}

function removeSecondsFromHHMMSS (time) {
    return time.slice(0, -3)
}
```

```css
#chartDiv #xaxis .domain {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
}

#chartDiv #xaxis text,
#yaxis text {
  font-size: 12px;
}

#chartDiv .axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  display: none;
}

#chartDiv .axis text {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartDiv">
</div>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartDiv">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inspect the DOM, you're gonna see that this rectangle is actually a bunch of rectangles, all in the same position. They are there, sitting on the top, because they have no `y` attribute.

The problem is not your code: the problem is actually your **data**. For each bus stop, you have a `yValue` starting at `101000017`...

```
"yValue": "101000017"
```

... and ending at `101000034`:

```
"yValue": "101000034"
```

Which are used for the ordinal scale. So, each bus stop should have **the same** y values, since they use the same ordinal scale.

However, for the last group, the `yValue`s starts at `101000026` and ends at `101000043`. When you use those values with the y scale, the last ones (from `101000034` on) return `undefined` and the rectangles end up in the top corner.

**Solution**: audit your data.

In the following snippet, I just changed the `yValues` of the last group to match the other groups.

Here is the working code:

```js
var dataset = [
    {
        "stopId": "165",
        "data": [
            {
                "yValue": "101000017",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "10:53:00",
                "stopId": "165",
                "passengers": 12
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000018",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "11:23:00",
                "stopId": "165",
                "passengers": 22
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000019",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "11:53:00",
                "stopId": "165",
                "passengers": 6
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000020",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "12:23:00",
                "stopId": "165",
                "passengers": 14
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000021",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "12:51:00",
                "stopId": "165",
                "passengers": 13
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000022",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "13:24:00",
                "stopId": "165",
                "passengers": 21
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000023",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "13:54:00",
                "stopId": "165",
                "passengers": 28
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000024",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "14:24:00",
                "stopId": "165",
                "passengers": 28
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000025",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "14:54:00",
                "stopId": "165",
                "passengers": 4
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000026",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "15:23:00",
                "stopId": "165",
                "passengers": 18
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000027",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "15:55:00",
                "stopId": "165",
                "passengers": 5
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000028",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:10:00",
                "stopId": "165",
                "passengers": 27
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000029",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:25:00",
                "stopId": "165",
                "passengers": 6
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000030",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:38:00",
                "stopId": "165",
                "passengers": 18
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000031",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:55:00",
                "stopId": "165",
                "passengers": 26
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000032",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "17:10:00",
                "stopId": "165",
                "passengers": 29
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000033",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "17:25:00",
                "stopId": "165",
                "passengers": 24
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000034",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "17:40:00",
                "stopId": "165",
                "passengers": 29
            }
        ],
        "name": "Passengers"
    },
    {
        "stopId": "65",
        "data": [       
            {
                "yValue": "101000017",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "10:54:00",
                "stopId": "65",
                "passengers": 20
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000018",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "11:24:00",
                "stopId": "65",
                "passengers": 22
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000019",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "11:54:00",
                "stopId": "65",
                "passengers": 8
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000020",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "12:24:00",
                "stopId": "65",
                "passengers": 27
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000021",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "12:52:00",
                "stopId": "65",
                "passengers": 26
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000022",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "13:25:00",
                "stopId": "65",
                "passengers": 24
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000023",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "13:55:00",
                "stopId": "65",
                "passengers": 25
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000024",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "14:25:00",
                "stopId": "65",
                "passengers": 28
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000025",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "14:55:00",
                "stopId": "65",
                "passengers": 7
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000026",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "15:24:00",
                "stopId": "65",
                "passengers": 23
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000027",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "15:56:00",
                "stopId": "65",
                "passengers": 18
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000028",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:11:00",
                "stopId": "65",
                "passengers": 4
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000029",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:26:00",
                "stopId": "65",
                "passengers": 29
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000030",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:39:00",
                "stopId": "65",
                "passengers": 19
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000031",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:56:00",
                "stopId": "65",
                "passengers": 28
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000032",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "17:11:00",
                "stopId": "65",
                "passengers": 21
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000033",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "17:26:00",
                "stopId": "65",
                "passengers": 26
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000034",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "17:41:00",
                "stopId": "65",
                "passengers": 19
            }
        ],
        "name": "Passengers"
    },
    {
        "stopId": "63",
        "data": [
            {
                "yValue": "101000017",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "10:55:00",
                "stopId": "63",
                "passengers": 10
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000018",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "11:25:00",
                "stopId": "63",
                "passengers": 9
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000019",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "11:55:00",
                "stopId": "63",
                "passengers": 21
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000020",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "12:25:00",
                "stopId": "63",
                "passengers": 28
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000021",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "12:53:00",
                "stopId": "63",
                "passengers": 8
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000022",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "13:26:00",
                "stopId": "63",
                "passengers": 13
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000023",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "13:56:00",
                "stopId": "63",
                "passengers": 29
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000024",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "14:26:00",
                "stopId": "63",
                "passengers": 28
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000025",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "14:56:00",
                "stopId": "63",
                "passengers": 14
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000026",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "15:25:00",
                "stopId": "63",
                "passengers": 30
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000027",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "15:57:00",
                "stopId": "63",
                "passengers": 21
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000028",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:12:00",
                "stopId": "63",
                "passengers": 10
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000029",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:27:00",
                "stopId": "63",
                "passengers": 16
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000030",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:40:00",
                "stopId": "63",
                "passengers": 24
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000031",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:57:00",
                "stopId": "63",
                "passengers": 3
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000032",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "17:12:00",
                "stopId": "63",
                "passengers": 15
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000033",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "17:27:00",
                "stopId": "63",
                "passengers": 23
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000034",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "17:42:00",
                "stopId": "63",
                "passengers": 21
            }
        ],
        "name": "Passengers"
    },
    {
        "stopId": "47",
        "data": [
            {
                "yValue": "101000017",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "10:56:00",
                "stopId": "47",
                "passengers": 13
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000018",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "11:26:00",
                "stopId": "47",
                "passengers": 7
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000019",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "11:56:00",
                "stopId": "47",
                "passengers": 21
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000020",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "12:26:00",
                "stopId": "47",
                "passengers": 22
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000021",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "12:54:00",
                "stopId": "47",
                "passengers": 28
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000022",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "13:27:00",
                "stopId": "47",
                "passengers": 30
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000023",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "13:57:00",
                "stopId": "47",
                "passengers": 20
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000024",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "14:27:00",
                "stopId": "47",
                "passengers": 17
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000025",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "14:57:00",
                "stopId": "47",
                "passengers": 14
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000026",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "15:26:00",
                "stopId": "47",
                "passengers": 11
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000027",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "15:58:00",
                "stopId": "47",
                "passengers": 28
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000028",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:13:00",
                "stopId": "47",
                "passengers": 7
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000029",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:28:00",
                "stopId": "47",
                "passengers": 24
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000030",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:41:00",
                "stopId": "47",
                "passengers": 29
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000031",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:58:00",
                "stopId": "47",
                "passengers": 19
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000032",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "17:13:00",
                "stopId": "47",
                "passengers": 23
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000033",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "17:28:00",
                "stopId": "47",
                "passengers": 19
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000034",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "17:43:00",
                "stopId": "47",
                "passengers": 12
            }
        ],
        "name": "Passengers"
    },
    {
        "stopId": "185",
        "data": [
            {
                "yValue": "101000017",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "15:27:00",
                "stopId": "185",
                "passengers": 23
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000018",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "15:59:00",
                "stopId": "185",
                "passengers": 11
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000019",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:14:00",
                "stopId": "185",
                "passengers": 24
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000020",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:29:00",
                "stopId": "185",
                "passengers": 16
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000021",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:42:00",
                "stopId": "185",
                "passengers": 22
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000022",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "16:59:00",
                "stopId": "185",
                "passengers": 23
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000023",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "17:14:00",
                "stopId": "185",
                "passengers": 27
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000024",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "17:29:00",
                "stopId": "185",
                "passengers": 29
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000025",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "17:44:00",
                "stopId": "185",
                "passengers": 24
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000026",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "17:59:00",
                "stopId": "185",
                "passengers": 19
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000027",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "18:14:00",
                "stopId": "185",
                "passengers": 23
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000028",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "18:29:00",
                "stopId": "185",
                "passengers": 6
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000029",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "18:44:00",
                "stopId": "185",
                "passengers": 24
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000030",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "18:59:00",
                "stopId": "185",
                "passengers": 26
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000031",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "19:29:00",
                "stopId": "185",
                "passengers": 21
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000032",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "19:59:00",
                "stopId": "185",
                "passengers": 23
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000033",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "20:25:00",
                "stopId": "185",
                "passengers": 20
            },
            {
                "yValue": "101000034",
                "xValue": 5,
                "time": "21:25:00",
                "stopId": "185",
                "passengers": 29
            }
        ],
        "name": "Passengers"
    }
];

var margins = {
  top: 12,
  left: 100,
  right: 50,
  bottom: 34
};

var numberOfRecords = 0;
var dataset = dataset.map(function(d) {
  numberOfRecords = 0;
  return d.data.map(function(o, i) {
    numberOfRecords++;
    return {
      y: o.xValue,
      x: o.yValue,
      name: d.name,
      stopId: o.stopId,
      passengers: o.passengers,
      time: o.time
    };
  });
});
d3.select(window).on("resize", throttle);
var stack = d3.layout.stack();
stack(dataset);
var dataset = dataset.map(function(group) {
  return group.map(function(d) {
    // Invert the x and y values, and y0 becomes x0
    return {
      x: d.y,
      y: d.x,
      x0: d.y0,
      name: d.name,
      stopId: d.stopId,
      passengers: d.passengers,
      time: d.time
    };
  });
});
var yValuesTripId = dataset[0].map(function(d) {
  return d.y;
});
var yValuesFirstStopTimes = dataset[0].map(function(d) {
  // return (d.time.slice(0, -3) + (Math.floor(Math.random() * (20000 - 1 + 1)) + 1));
  return removeSecondsFromHHMMSS(d.time);
});
var yValuesLastStopTimes = dataset[dataset.length - 1].map(function(d) {
  // return (d.time.slice(0, -3) + (Math.floor(Math.random() * (20000 - 1 + 1)) + 1));
  return removeSecondsFromHHMMSS(d.time);
});
var xMax = d3.max(dataset, function(group) {
  return d3.max(group, function(d) {
    return d.x + d.x0;
  });
});
var tooltip = d3.select("#chartDiv")
  .append('div')
  .attr('id', 'tooltip')
  .attr('class', 'hidden');

const chartArea = $("#chartDiv");
var width = chartArea.innerWidth() - margins.left - margins.right;
var barHeight = 10;
var height = (numberOfRecords * 15) - margins.top - margins.bottom;
var svg, xScale, yScaleLeft, yScaleRight, rects;

draw(width, height);

function draw(width, height) {

  svg = d3.select("#chartDiv")
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', width + margins.left + margins.right)
    .attr('height', height + margins.top + margins.bottom)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margins.left + ',' + margins.top + ')');
    
  xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, xMax])
    .range([0, width - margins.right]);

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient('bottom')
    .ticks(0);

    yScaleLeft = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(yValuesTripId)
        .rangeRoundBands([0, height], .1); 
    var yAxisLeft = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yScaleLeft)
        .orient('left')
        .tickFormat(function(d, i) {
            return yValuesFirstStopTimes[i];
        });

    yScaleRight = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(yValuesTripId)
        .rangeRoundBands([0, height], .1);
    var yAxisRight = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yScaleRight)
        .orient('right')
        .tickPadding(-25)
        .tickFormat(function(d, i) {
            return yValuesLastStopTimes[i];
        });

  var groups = svg.selectAll('g')
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append('g');

  rects = groups.selectAll('rect')
    .data(function(d) {
      return d;
    })
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x', function(d) {
      return xScale(d.x0);
    })
    .attr('y', function(d, i) {
      return yScaleLeft(d.y);
    })
    .attr('height', function(d) {
      return barHeight;
    })
    .attr('width', function(d) {
      return xScale(d.x);
    })
    .attr('fill', function(d) {
      return getColor(d.passengers);
    })
    .attr('stroke', 'white')
    .on('mouseover', function(d) {

      var xPos = d3.event.pageX - 310;
      var yPos = d3.event.pageY - 110;

      d3.select('#tooltip')
        .style("left", xPos + "px")
        .style("top", yPos + "px")
        .style('width', '250px')
        .text("Trip " + d.y + '|Passengers:' + d.passengers + '|Stop ' + d.stopId + '|time ' + removeSecondsFromHHMMSS(d.time));

      d3.select('#tooltip').classed('hidden', false);
    })
    .on('mouseout', function() {
      d3.select('#tooltip').classed('hidden', true);
    });
  svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis')
    .attr('id','busOccupancyChartXAxis')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
    .call(xAxis);
  svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis')
    .call(yAxisLeft);
  svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", 0 - margins.left)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .text("Departure Time");
  const newWidth = width - 20;
  svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis')
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + newWidth + ",0)")
    .call(yAxisRight);
svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", width - margins.right + 10)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .text("Arrival Time");
}

function redraw() {
  width = chartArea.innerWidth() - margins.left - margins.right;
  d3.select('svg').remove();
  d3.select('#legend').remove();
  draw(width, height);
}
var throttleTimer;

function throttle() {
  window.clearTimeout(throttleTimer);
  throttleTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
    redraw();
  }, 200);
}

function getColor(numberOfPassengers) {
  cellColor = "";
  if (numberOfPassengers < 10) {
    cellColor = "#585858";
  } else if (numberOfPassengers < 20) {
    cellColor = "#FFCC00";
  } else if (numberOfPassengers < 25) {
    cellColor = "#FF3300";
  } else {
    cellColor = "#A00000";
  }
  return cellColor;
}

function removeSecondsFromHHMMSS (time) {
    return time.slice(0, -3)
}
```

```css
#chartDiv #xaxis .domain {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
}

#chartDiv #xaxis text,
#yaxis text {
  font-size: 12px;
}

#chartDiv .axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  display: none;
}

#chartDiv .axis text {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartDiv">
</div>
```